# Extending MetricsServlet with custom metric types

Tags: dropwizard, metrics

I am using Dropwizard 0.8.1 with Metrics 3.1.0 and am currently in the process trying to add a couple of nonstandard metrics types. I would like to be able to use the MetricsServlet to show a couple of custom values of which none match any of the available counters, gauge etc. types. The trouble is that I can't find any extension points except for more reporters. Is that possible at all?

Examples of what I want to do:

- Add local storage metric
- Add a list of upstream server and their states

I realize that in the strictest definition of the metrics package these are not "metrics" in the purest sense. Nevertheless, this information is vital for operation and adding them to the existing infrastructure would save me from creating a lot of overhead.

Comment: I think you should give an example which values you want to add. I can't imagine what is missing / can't be done with the types that are already supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that most of the state monitoring I wanted to do can be achieved by simply adding a `Gauge<Map>` type. Since the Map can contain arbitrary nested data (the map is simply dumped into the jackson serializer by the MetricsServlet), it leaves enough room for extensions.